# sync login with Facebook And Google Account from Android App to Web

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, google-signin

I try to sync login with Facebook And Google Account from Android App to Web.

After Login success from App i need to sync login information to server to sync with website.

so what information i should to send to server ?

Do I need to check session or token from server ?